# Why my simple SQLite app on Android doesn´t work?

Tags: android, sqlite

When I run a project on emulator I get a message "Unfortunately, dezo12 has stopped".

LogCat doesn't show anything, and I also tried to run directly on smartphone, but my app also crashed.

I work with eclipse neon and I recently install all needed tools in Android sdk manager.

Here is a code:

`MAIN ACTIVITY.java`

```
package com.example.dezo12;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("rex.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        database.execSQL("create table if not exist sampletable(name text, location text)");
        database.execSQL("insert into sampletable values('dezo', 'bela')");
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from sampletable", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = cursor.getString(0);
        String location = cursor.getString(1);
        textView.setText(name+ "/n" +location);


        database.close();

    }
}
```

`ACTIVITY_MAIN xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dezo12"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `LogCat doesnt show anything` That is pretty hard to believe...

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper` should ideally be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake to write "exists" . Edit this line like this

```
database.execSQL("create table if not exists sampletable(name text, location text)");
```

Comment: Thanks bedesten1618 for your answer.

Comment: As you wrote, problem was with wrong spelled " exists" word.